# Update all columns from another table depending on id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need to update one table from another table. I have to update all columns depending on certain id numbers, for example id=5 and id=10. I tried

```
update Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST
set Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.id = p.id
from SomedatabaseTest.dbo.CONTHIST p
where Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.id= 17448
and p.id = 17448
```

So you can see that I'm trying to update it from SomedatabaseTest where i have my restored datas but even though I'm not sure how to update all columns and datas for certain id. I tried it and got some changes but I forgot to mention that besides **id** I have **cnkey** for each record and one user can have couple of records and automatically has a couple of different cnkey-s. So can you help me again please? I'm looking forward to your help!! :D

Comment: Why are you setting Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.id with p.PVKEY?

Comment: I made a mistake, it's id and not pvkey

Comment: But if both id's are 17448 then you are not updating anything.

Comment: I'm just trying to put some condition where id from one table has to be equal to id from another table.

Comment: Ok, but on the Set part you're assigning a value, not comparing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST
    SET ID = A.ID,
       ,COLUMN1 = A.COLUMN1
       ,COLUMN2 = A.COLUMN2
FROM SomedatabaseTest.dbo.CONTHIST P, TABLE2 A
   WHERE P.id = A.id 
   AND p.id = '17448'
```

TABLE2 is where the data will be coming from

Answer (score 0):

First make a relationship between two tables and then update your columns as you wish.

```
update Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST
set Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.id = p.id 
[add as many columns as you need to update here]
from Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST inner join SomedatabaseTest.dbo.CONTHIST p
on Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.id = p.id 
where Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.id= 17448
and p.id = 17448 and p.cnkey = [something];
```

Comment: I tried it and got some changes but I forgot to mention that besides id I have cnkey for each record and one user can have couple of records and automatically has a couple of different cnkey-s. So can you help me again please? :D

Comment: Add cnkey = somethimg in where clause.

Comment: Thank you very much on your solution and great help. I finally made it, everything is now like it should be! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you need is:

```
UPDATE Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST
SET a.id = p.id,
    a.column1 = p.column1,
    a.column2 = p.column2,
    ...
FROM SomedatabaseTest.dbo.CONTHIST p
INNER JOIN Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST a
ON a.id = p.id
WHERE a.id = 17448
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this it's what you are looking for (I wouldn't update id, since it's a PK and the value must be the same)

```
update Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST
  set Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.field1 = p.field1,
      [.....]
      Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.fieldn = p.fieldn
from SomedatabaseTest.dbo.CONTHIST p
where Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.id = p.id
  and Somedatabase.dbo.CONTHIST.cnKey = p.cnKey
  and p.id=17448;
```